# Kafka timing out because of Docker latency

Tags: python, docker, jenkins, apache-kafka

I am totally new to Kafka *and* Docker, and have been handed a problem to fix. Our Continuous Integration tests for Kafka (Apache) queues run just fine on local machines, but when on the Jenkins CI server, occasionally fail with this sort of error:

```
%3|1508247800.270|FAIL|art#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/bootstrap]: localhost:9092/bootstrap: Connect to ipv4#127.0.0.1:9092 failed: Connection refused
%3|1508247800.270|ERROR|art#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/bootstrap]: localhost:9092/bootstrap: Connect to ipv4#127.0.0.1:9092 failed: Connection refused
%3|1508247800.270|ERROR|art#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/bootstrap]: 1/1 brokers are down
```

The working theory is that the Docker image takes time to get started, by which time the Kafka producer has given up. The offending code is

```
    producer_properties = {
        'bootstrap.servers': self._job_queue.bootstrap_server,
        'client.id': self._job_queue.client_id
    }
    try:
        self._producer = kafka.Producer(**producer_properties)
    except:
        print("Bang!")
```

with the error lines above appearing in the creation of the producer. However, no exception is raised, and the call returns an otherwise valid looking producer, so I can't programmatically test the presence of the broker endpoint. Is there an API to check the status of a broker?

Comment: Are you running the Kafka broker from the same docker container ? And which Python Kafka library are you using?

Comment: I think (having just had this problem thrown at me with no prior exposure to the tech) that the Kafka broker is in the same Docker container, and we are using the Adobe Confluent  Kafka library.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the client doesn't throw exception if connection to broker fails. It actually tries to connect to bootstrap servers when first time producer tries to send the message. If connection fails, it repeatedly tries to connect to any of the brokers passed in the bootstrap list. Eventually, if the brokers come up, send will happen (and we may check the status in the callback function).
The confluent kafka python library is using librdkafka library and this client doesn't seem to have proper documentation. Some of the Kafka producer option specified by Kafka protocol, seem not supported by librdkafka.

Here is the sample code with callback I used:

```
from confluent_kafka import Producer

def notifyme(err, msg):
    print err, msg.key(), msg.value()

p = Producer({'bootstrap.servers': '127.0.0.1:9092', 'retry.backoff.ms' : 100,
        'message.send.max.retries' : 20,
        "reconnect.backoff.jitter.ms" :  2000})
try:
    p.produce(topic='sometopic', value='this is data', on_delivery=notifyme)
except Exception as e:
    print e
p.flush()
```

Also, checking for the presence of the broker, you may just telnet to the broker ip on its port (in this example it is 9092). And on the Zookeeper used by Kafka cluster, you may check the contents of the znodes under /brokers/ids

Comment: That looks useful. I have registered an error callback (NOT the on_delivery callback) which is being hit when produce() is followed by flush(). But will Kafka still try to add the message if and when the broker becomes available? Or can I assume the request needs to be retried.

Comment: How are you registering the error callback? Generally, error or success callback is invoked by the library after successfully sending the message to Kafka or after it has given up on that message on failure (may be after few retries) and our code has to decide whether to push that message again via the producer (in case of failure).

Comment: `producer_properties = {
        'bootstrap.servers': self._job_queue.bootstrap_server,
        'error_cb': self.__on_error,
        'client.id': self._job_queue.client_id,
    }
    return kafka.Producer(**producer_properties)`

When you call flush() a couple of times the errors start coming back (once doesn't seem to do it).

Comment: confluent-kafka-python documentation is available here: https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/index.html  API ref here: https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that seems to work for me. If it looks a bit Frankenstein, then you are right, it is! If there is a clean solution, I look forward to seeing it:

```
import time
import uuid
from threading import Event
from typing import Dict

import confluent_kafka as kafka
# pylint: disable=no-name-in-module
from confluent_kafka.cimpl import KafkaError

# more imports...

LOG = # ...


# Default number of times to retry connection to Kafka Broker
_DEFAULT_RETRIES = 3

# Default time in seconds to wait between connection attempts
_DEFAULT_RETRY_DELAY_S = 5.0

# Number of times to scan for an error after initiating the connection. It appears that calling
# flush() once on a producer after construction isn't sufficient to catch the 'broker not available'
# # error. At least twice seems to work.
_NUM_ERROR_SCANS = 2


class JobProducer(object):
    def __init__(self, connection_retries: int=_DEFAULT_RETRIES,
                 retry_delay_s: float=_DEFAULT_RETRY_DELAY_S) -> None:
        """
        Constructs a producer.
        :param connection_retries: how many times to retry the connection before raising a
        RuntimeError. If 0, retry forever.
        :param retry_delay_s: how long to wait between retries in seconds.
        """
        self.__error_event = Event()
        self._job_queue = JobQueue()
        self._producer = self.__wait_for_broker(connection_retries, retry_delay_s)
        self._topic = self._job_queue.topic

    def produce_job(self, job_definition: Dict) -> None:
        """
        Produce a job definition on the queue
        :param job_definition: definition of the job to be executed
        """
        value = ... # Conversion to JSON
        key = str(uuid.uuid4())
        LOG.info('Produced message: %s', value)

        self.__error_event.clear()
        self._producer.produce(self._topic,
                               value=value,
                               key=key,
                               on_delivery=self._on_delivery)
        self._producer.flush(self._job_queue.flush_timeout)

    @staticmethod
    def _on_delivery(error, message):
        if error:
            LOG.error('Failed to produce job %s, with error: %s', message.key(), error)

    def __create_producer(self) -> kafka.Producer:
        producer_properties = {
            'bootstrap.servers': self._job_queue.bootstrap_server,
            'error_cb': self.__on_error,
            'client.id': self._job_queue.client_id,
        }
        return kafka.Producer(**producer_properties)

    def __wait_for_broker(self, retries: int, delay: float) -> kafka.Producer:
        retry_count = 0
        while True:
            self.__error_event.clear()
            producer = self.__create_producer()
            # Need to call flush() several times with a delay between to ensure errors are caught.
            if not self.__error_event.is_set():
                for _ in range(_NUM_ERROR_SCANS):
                    producer.flush(0.1)
                    if self.__error_event.is_set():
                        break
                    time.sleep(0.1)
                else:
                    # Success: no errors.
                    return producer

            # If we get to here, the error callback was invoked.
            retry_count += 1
            if retries == 0:
                msg = '({})'.format(retry_count)
            else:
                if retry_count <= retries:
                    msg = '({}/{})'.format(retry_count, retries)
                else:
                    raise RuntimeError('JobProducer timed out')

            LOG.warn('JobProducer: could not connect to broker, will retry %s', msg)
            time.sleep(delay)

    def __on_error(self, error: KafkaError) -> None:
        LOG.error('KafkaError: %s', error.str())
        self.__error_event.set()
```